# CloudSQL postgres performance issues

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We recently migrated from on-premise SQL Server to cloudSQL for Postgres in GCP. The migration was successful but we are facing performance issue in postgres. The query which was taking only 1 seconds is taking more than 16 seconds in Postgres. We tried adding indexes but still the performance is bad. Can you please let me know any performance improvement tips on Postgres?

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this SQL statement? And the SQL itself and the ddl for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text as an update to your original question.

Comment: Cloud databases are either slow or expensive, but a factor of 16 warrants closer investigation.

Comment: If you run the exact same query multiple times in a row, does subsequent execution faster?

Comment: No the subsequent run is not faster.